# Css menu dropdown ao abrir deve deixar a página escura

Tags: css

Fiz um menu dropdown com bootstrap, mas quero que quando esse menu abra (ele abre em cima do conteúdo da página), toda a página fique num efeito opaco.
Tentei fazer algo assim mexendo no background, mas não ficou legal nas imagens, queria tipo umaa camada mais escura por cima de toda a página.

```
 <header class="header">
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <main class="content">
 </main>
 <footer class="footer"><p>Copyrights</p></footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com certeza há maneiras de fazer que isso fique bem melhor, porém essa é a forma que achei mais fácil.

Adicionei uma div com o id `back`;

Coloquei os itens da lista com a classe `menu-item`;

Coloquei o id `menu` no botão;

Adicionei o CSS e o JavaScript.

```js
window.onload = function(){
menu = document.getElementById('menu');
back = document.getElementById('back');
item = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');

for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
    item[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ back.style.display = 'none'});
}

menu.addEventListener('click', function(){ back.style.display = 'block' });
back.addEventListener('click', function(){ back.style.display = 'none' });
}
```

```css
#back{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="header">
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button id="menu" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">2</a></li>
     <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 <main class="content">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </main>
 <footer class="footer"><p>Copyrights</p></footer>
 <div id="back"></div>
```

Comment: Uma transição na div criada de id=back criaria um efeito interessante na hora da mudança.

Comment: @BrunoCastro, concordo, porém não sei como fazer... Se souber, me diz como coloco.

Comment: Algumas pequenas mudanças seriam necessárias: `.dropdown {   z-index: 10; }`, `#back { opacity: 0;   -webkit-transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.2s;   transition: opacity ease-in-out 0.2s; }`. Depois é só trocar o JS pra funcionar com diferença de opacity 0 e 1; não display none e block.

Comment: olá, obrigada, mas que queria que o conteúdo do fundo continuasse aparecendo, somente com uma base mais escura por cima.

Comment: @sabrinabgbc O conteúdo continua aparecendo atrás, apenas não há nenhum conteúdo atrás para ser visto no exemplo dele.

Comment: Agora há conteúdo... e continua aparecendo...

Comment: era isso mesmo, obrigada !